# Weird behaviour of TextInputEditText if onFocusChangeListener is hooked

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext, onfocuschangelistener

I have two `EditText` in my `Activity`, each of one is inside `TextInputLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilm"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etlogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tilm"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etpass"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
                android:hint="@string/pass"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Also, in code, I have the same `onFocusChangeListener` hooked:

```
focusChangeListener=new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(hasFocus){
                scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    };
```

(This is in order that when the keyboard appears, an `ScrollView` that is in my layout goes down, so the user can see other elements of the UI that are below, buttons specifically).

Also, both `TextInputEditText` have a `TextWatcher`:

```
textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(ValidateLogin(login.getText().toString()) && pass.getText().length()>0){
                entrar.setEnabled(true);//This is a button
            }else{
                if(entrar.isEnabled()){
                    entrar.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
login.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    pass.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    login.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
    pass.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
```

The problem is, when the second `TextInputEditText` gain focus, the cursor goes automatically to the first one, and I can't type anything in the second one, since the focus goes immediately to the first one. I'd like this not to happen, keep my `onFocusChangeListener` in both `TextInputEditText`, and not change the focus automatically.

I have tried to make another `OnFocusChangeListener` for the second `TextInputEditText`, with no luck. If I remove the `onFocusChangeListener`, the focus maintains in the `TextInputEditText`, but obviously the `ScrollView` doesn't moves.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of ScrollView.fullScroll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fullScroll(int)) says:

> This method will scroll the view to the top or bottom and **give the focus to the topmost/bottommost component in the new visible area.**

The problem probably is that the first `TextInputEditText` is the "topmost component in the new visible area" of the `ScrollView`, hence it is given focus automatically.

Possible solutions could be:

- Instead of `fullScroll`, use

  ```
  int scrollY = Math.max(0, content.getHeight() - scrollView.getHeight()); // where content is the content view of the scroll view
  scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollY); // or scrollTo if you don't want animation
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing this, the focus goes from one TextInputEditText to another endlessly.

Comment: Tried. By doing that, the scrollView goes way above the rest of the view components, and nothing can be seen in the device, but the background of the Activity layout.

Comment: Updated again, please try it.

Comment: Its working now, than you very much for your help! (I have to wait 22 hours to award you the bounty, will not forget)